# Python junit2html : Could not find test suites in results xml

Tags: python, robotframework

I am not able to parse the sample xml (output.xml) file generated from Robot Framework.
I want to create an output.html file from the xml file above.

I am getting the below error after running the below command from terminal.
`junit2html output.xml output.html`

Here is the error snippet I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/junit2html", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(start())
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/junit2htmlreport/runner.py", line 103, in start
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/junit2htmlreport/runner.py", line 90, in run
    report = parser.Junit(args[0])
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/junit2htmlreport/parser.py", line 340, in __init__
    self.process()
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/junit2htmlreport/parser.py", line 376, in process
    raise ParserError("could not find test suites in results xml")
junit2htmlreport.parser.ParserError: could not find test suites in results xml
```

I am expecting an HTML file should be generated after converting the output.xml to output.html in human readable format. So that I can paste it in email body

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run this for output.xml because it is Robot Framework format, no junit. You must run your test with `robot --xunit junit.xml tests` parameter. Then you are able to run `junit2html junit.xml output.html`